# Is it possible to count the number of elements from one array in another and vice versa in a single loop?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, performance, compare

I have a double array x and a double array y. Both can have duplicates elements.

```
const double MAX = 10000.0;
const int X_LENGTH = 10000;
const int Y_LENGTH = 10000;
const double TOLERANCE = 0.01;

Random random = new Random();

double[] x = new double[X_LENGTH];
for(int i = 0; i < X_LENGTH; i++)
{
        x[i] = MAX * random.NextDouble();
}

double[] y = new double[Y_LENGTH];
for(int j = 0; j < Y_LENGTH; j++)
{
        y[j] = MAX * random.NextDouble();
}
```

I am trying to count how many elements in array x are found in array y within a tolerance, and how many elements in array y are found in array x within the same tolerance. Note that these numbers can be different. The simplest way to do this is with two sets of two embedded loops:

```
int x_matches = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < X_LENGTH; i++)
{
        for(int j = 0; j < Y_LENGTH; j++)
        {
                if(Math.Abs(x[i] - y[j]) <= TOLERANCE)
                {
                        x_matches++;
                        break;
                }
        }
}

int y_matches = 0;
for(int j = 0; j < Y_LENGTH; j++)
{
        for(int i = 0; i < X_LENGTH; i++)
        {
                if(Math.Abs(x[i] - y[j]) <= TOLERANCE)
                {
                        y_matches++;
                        break;
                }
        }
}
```

However, this code is run thousands of times and is the main bottleneck in the software. I am trying to speed it up. I have already optimized by sorting both arrays first and then asynchronously iterating through them.

```
Array.Sort(x);
Array.Sort(y);

int x_matches_2 = 0;
int i2 = 0;
int j2 = 0;
while(i2 < X_LENGTH && j2 < Y_LENGTH)
{
        if(Math.Abs(x[i2] - y[j2]) <= TOLERANCE)
        {
                x_matches_2++;
                i2++;
        }
        else if(x[i2] < y[j2])
        {
                i2++;
        }
        else if(x[i2] > y[j2])
        {
                j2++;
        }
}

int y_matches_2 = 0;
int i3 = 0;
int j3 = 0;
while(i3 < X_LENGTH && j3 < Y_LENGTH)
{
        if(Math.Abs(x[i3] - y[j3]) <= TOLERANCE)
        {
                y_matches_2++;
                j3++;
        }
        else if(x[i3] < y[j3])
        {
                i3++;
        }
        else if(x[i3] > y[j3])
        {
                j3++;
        }
}
```

I am wondering if anybody knows of a way to merge these two loops into one and still obtain the same answer. I can only come up with this:

```
int x_matches_2 = 0;
int y_matches_2 = 0;
bool[] y_matched = new bool[Y_LENGTH];
for(int i = 0; i < X_LENGTH; i++)
{
        bool x_matched = false;

        for(int j = 0; j < Y_LENGTH; j++)
        {
                if(Math.Abs(x[i] - y[j]) <= TOLERANCE)
                {
                        if(!x_matched)
                        {
                                x_matches_2++;
                                x_matched = true;
                        }
                        if(!y_matched[j])
                        {
                                y_matches_2++;
                                y_matched[j] = true;
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

It doesn't require sorting; however, it ends up being slower because more comparisons must be done.

P.S. This is an oversimplification of my actual problem, but I think the solution to this will apply to both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to have a single loop, but you will process some part of each array more than once.

```
public static void JustDoIt(double[] x, double[] y)
{
    Array.Sort(x);
    Array.Sort(y);

    bool mustContinue = true;
    bool isXTurns;
    bool withinTolerance;

    int lastBase_x = 0;
    int lastBase_y = 0;

    int lastMatch_x = 0;
    int lastMatch_y = 0;

    int current_x = 0;
    int current_y = 0;

    int matchedCount_x = 0;
    int matchedCount_y = 0;

    double yourTolerance = 0.001;

    while (mustContinue)
    {
        isXTurns = x[current_x] <= y[current_y];

        if (isXTurns)
        {
            withinTolerance = (y[current_y] - x[current_x] <= yourTolerance);
        }
        else
        {
            withinTolerance = (x[current_x] - y[current_y] <= yourTolerance);
        }

        if (withinTolerance)
        {
            if (isXTurns)
            {
                if (current_x > lastMatch_x)
                {
                    matchedCount_x++;
                    lastMatch_x = current_x;
                }

                if (current_y > lastMatch_y)
                {
                    matchedCount_y++;
                    lastMatch_y = current_y;
                }

                if (current_y + 1 < y.Length)
                {
                    current_y++;
                }
                else if (current_x + 1 < x.Length)
                {
                    current_x++;
                }
                else
                {
                    mustContinue = false;
                }

            }
            else
            {
                if (current_y > lastMatch_y)
                {
                    matchedCount_y++;
                    lastMatch_y = current_y;
                } 

                if (current_x > lastMatch_x)
                {
                    matchedCount_x++;
                    lastMatch_x = current_x;
                }

                if (current_x + 1 < x.Length)
                {
                    current_x++;
                }
                else if (current_y + 1 < y.Length)
                {
                    current_y++;
                }
                else
                {
                    mustContinue = false;
                }
            }

        }
        else
        {
            if (isXTurns)
            {
                lastBase_x++;
                mustContinue = lastBase_x < x.Length;
            }
            else
            {
                lastBase_y++;
                mustContinue = lastBase_y < y.Length;
            }

            current_x = lastBase_x;
            current_y = lastBase_y;
        }
    }
}
```

Some odd results you'll get : if you have 2 arrays of 2 elements each, it's possible that you have more than 2 match from x to y or y to x. It happens cause x[0] can match with y[0] ans y[1], so can x[1]. This way, you'd end up with 4 match in both "direction". For example, when I ran this code with 2 arrays of 1000 items each, I had 1048 matches in one, and 978 in the other. I hope it helps.

**Edit**: Here is a generic version :

```
public static void JustDoIt<T>(IEnumerable<T> items_x, IEnumerable<T> items_y, out int matchedCount_x, out int matchedCount_y, IComparer<T> comparer, Func<T, T, bool> toleranceReferee)
{

    T[] x = items_x.OrderBy(item => item, comparer).ToArray();
    T[] y = items_y.OrderBy(item => item, comparer).ToArray();

    bool mustContinue = true;
    bool isXTurns;
    bool withinTolerance;

    int lastBase_x = 0;
    int lastBase_y = 0;

    int lastMatch_x = 0;
    int lastMatch_y = 0;

    int current_x = 0;
    int current_y = 0;

    matchedCount_x = 0;
    matchedCount_y = 0;

    while (mustContinue)
    {
        isXTurns = comparer.Compare(x[current_x], y[current_y]) <= 0;

        withinTolerance = toleranceReferee(x[current_x], y[current_y]);

        if (withinTolerance)
        {
            if (isXTurns)
            {
                if (current_x > lastMatch_x)
                {
                    matchedCount_x++;
                    lastMatch_x = current_x;
                }

                if (current_y > lastMatch_y)
                {
                    matchedCount_y++;
                    lastMatch_y = current_y;
                }

                if (current_y + 1 < y.Length)
                {
                    current_y++;
                }
                else if (current_x + 1 < x.Length)
                {
                    current_x++;
                }
                else
                {
                    mustContinue = false;
                }

            }
            else
            {
                if (current_y > lastMatch_y)
                {
                    matchedCount_y++;
                    lastMatch_y = current_y;
                }

                if (current_x > lastMatch_x)
                {
                    matchedCount_x++;
                    lastMatch_x = current_x;
                }

                if (current_x + 1 < x.Length)
                {
                    current_x++;
                }
                else if (current_y + 1 < y.Length)
                {
                    current_y++;
                }
                else
                {
                    mustContinue = false;
                }
            }

        }
        else
        {
            if (isXTurns)
            {
                lastBase_x++;
                mustContinue = lastBase_x < x.Length;
            }
            else
            {
                lastBase_y++;
                mustContinue = lastBase_y < y.Length;
            }

            current_x = lastBase_x;
            current_y = lastBase_y;
        }
    }
}
```

With an example of how you'd call it for int :

```
List<int> x2 = new List<int>() { 2, 4, 4, 6, 9, 9 };    // To test an IEnumerable
IEnumerable<int> y2 = new int[] { 1, 3, 3, 4, 6, 9 };   // To test another

int xcount;
int ycount;

SingleLoop.JustDoIt(
    x2,
    y2,
    out xcount,
    out ycount,
    Comparer<int>.Default,
   (currentX, currentY) => { return currentX == currentY; });
```

Comment: This is the kind of solution I am looking for, but I am getting lower counts than expected from this function (they both seem to be about half the correct value).

Comment: lol, yes. I can see why. I'll edit the solution by adding 2 lines. You'll be able to spot them by the comment on their right. Once you confirm you saw the changes, I'll re-edit the answer to show only the final code.

Comment: Still not right--now the counts are too high. The edit can't be correct because matchedCount_x will always equal matchedCount_y, which is not always the case.

Comment: Ah! I think I found it. I edited the answer. The "add line" refers to the first (erroneous) solution I gave.

Comment: Very close, but still no. :-) The counts always seem to be a few higher than they should be.

Comment: Can you give me an example? Like 2 small sets of doubles, and the result you'd expect. I won't be able to do this now (working) but I'll check this when I get home in about 3h.

Comment: Sure. Let's say x is { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 } and y is { 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4 }, and a tolerance 0 for simplicity. I would expect x matches to y to be 3 and y matches to x to be 6. However, I am getting the reverse with your code (seems to be just a coincidence in this case).

Comment: The fact that it's reverse is by design. It's easy enough to reverse it back. Do you have an example where the reverse is not what you wanted?

Comment: Sure, x = { 2, 4, 4, 6, 9 ,9 }, y = { 1, 3, 3, 4, 6, 9 }, tolerance = 0. x matches should be 5, y matches should be 3. Your function gives 4 and 4.

Comment: Ok, I think I got it this time! I didn't mark my edits, but I'm sure you'll see them quickly enough. I should make this method generic now :-D

Comment: Works perfect and very fast. Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: I enjoyed the challenge, I'm glad it helps!

Answer (score 2):

Make a `HashSet<int>` for both arrays and populate them with the elements of the arrays. Traverse both arrays, look up elements in corresponding (opposite) `HashSet` - `HashSet` lookup is O(1) so overall effort is O(m+n) with m,n being the array sizes.

Comment: Well, I was wrong that the solution would apply to both. In my actual problem it is not just plain matching, there is a tolerance. So HashSets won't work.

Comment: @Craig - That doesn't matter. You can perform your tolerance matching within your own custom IEqualityComparer. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359100.aspx This answer still stands

Comment: @Polity: Unless I am misunderstanding the implementation, it seems like that solution would just shift the question to how to define an efficient hash code. Could you post some code to clarify?

Comment: Even when I return the same hash code for everything (just ignoring performance for now), the counts computed with the HashSet/custom IEqualityComparer come out a little low.

Comment: @Craig - just use your current logic: return (Math.Abs(x[i] - y[j]) <= TOLERANCE);

Comment: @Craig - I see, the problem must be that there is both a matching of source items with source items and source items with destination items. Therefore it's not possible to built a valid hashset with a custom IEqualityComparer on the way i proposed. Let me think about this....

Comment: @Polity: Right, for the Equals method. But IEqualityComparer requires you define the GetHashCode method too.

Comment: @Polity: I think to implement IEqualityComparer correctly, Equals has to be transitive and `a.Equals(b)` has to imply `a.GetHashCode() == b.GetHashCode()`. That's not possible for comparison with tolerance, because it's not transitive

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it has to be O(n*m) in worst case - all elements of one array are "similar" to all elements in another array - you have to run comparison for each pair.

Since you already have sorting, consider dividing each array into ranges (i.e. 20 ranges with about 50 numbers in each [0, 0.05), [0.05, 0.1),..[0.95, 1]) so you can compare ranges first and than compare individual numbers - depending on the data (works good with random or other distribution without huge clumps of values) you may decrease number of comparisons significantly.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is actually in the range [0..1] like `Random.NextDouble()`, then you could just make an array with 1000 (=1/TOLERANCE) bins, one for every [x..x+TOLERANCE] range in the total range. Put each value in one array into its bin. Then go over the other array and compare each value to the contents of the closest bin, the bin before and the one after.

**Edit in response to changed question**: Instead of using a flat array with Range/Tolerance elements, you could use a hash table: Use `HashFunction(x/Tolerance)` as hash key to the items `x` in the first array, then compare every element `y` in the second array with the elements stored for the hashes `HashFunction(y/Tolerance-1)`, `HashFunction(y/Tolerance)`, `HashFunction(y/Tolerance+1)`. In theory, a hash table access is O(1), so the whole operation would be O(m+n)

Comment: The data is not actually in a neat range like that. And the tolerance is variable. I have edited the question to be a little more realistic.

Comment: Can you provide some code? I would have thought you could do this by providing a custom IEqualityComparer to HashSet (above), but even when I returned a constant from GetHashCode()--disregarding performance temporarily--the counts didn't come out right.